# After the call of functuion 47h of int 21h i don't get any visible results

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I'm trying to get the current direcotrry's path in a variable to be printed after, but after i ran this code bearly anything happend

```
assume ds:data, cs:code
data segment
    directory db 64 dup(?),"$"
data ends

code segment
start:
;data assignment
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
;get the path
mov dl,0
mov si,offset directory
mov ah, 47h
mov al,0
int 21h
; print it
mov ah,09h
mov dx, offset directory
int 21h
; view the results
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov ah ,4CH
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

I also read online that 47h returns a ASCIIZ , i know it's an ASCII with a terminal 0. Is this the problem ? I got to declare my variable in a certian way for it to support ASCIIZ?

Comment: Works for me, although I had hard time to actually realize it does. Maybe you are in the same trap. My dosbox configuration to test TASM experiments mounts the directory with .asm files as root directory. When I run your code there, the returned values CF=0, AX=0x100 signal success, yet the buffer is still full of zeroes. But that is [correct behaviour!](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-47.html) *"the leading slash "\" and drive designator are omitted"*  ... When I did put the exe into `H` subdirectory, the first byte of buffer is correctly set to `'H'`, remaining is zeroed.

Comment: About the display by `int 21h,9` service: it will print zeroes in buffer as spaces, so when the dosbox is waiting for key, the cursor is blinking at 65th column of screen. If you want to display only the directory without zeroes, you will have to scan the buffer and set first zero to `'$'` to terminate string right after the directory name. (you may want to add also `13, 10` bytes for newline, but make sure you have enough space in memory if directory name takes full 64B).

Comment: I just checked it. It works in emu8086 but not in TASM.

Comment: well, @Ped7g, you are right i just fell into that trap. I found this  [link](http://www.ousob.com/ng/asm/ng5b7d1.php) in the meentime that says if the sourse is in the root directory it will return a null asciiz. thank you for your time .

Comment: @Ahtisham ?? what does it do in emu8086, and what does not in TASM? (as it works for me in dosbox+tasm, but I don't have emu8086)

Comment: @Ped7g In emu8086 it displays the current directory while as in Tasm it displays nothing.

Comment: @Ahtisham "in tasm" - TASM is assembler, you can't run .exe inside it. Where do you run it? What was the current directory? How does emu8086 display it's current directory? If emu8086 does run for example "c:\emu8086\build\test.exe" in build directory, it should display "emu8086\build" .. if it has also "c:\" at beginning, then that's not how original DOS works.

Comment: @Ped7g For Tasm the location is: **E:\Education\Assembly\Programs\test.asm** and for emu8086 location is: **E:\emu\binaries\MyBuild\test.asm**. Now with emu8086 it displays `MyBuild\ ` which is right but with Tasm it displays nothing.

Comment: @Ahtisham well, it's not clear what is your environment to run the EXE file, can you before executing it run `dir /w` what it will display at top? For me it displays inside the "H" subdirectory: `Directory of C:\H\.`  (in dosbox, I'm using dosbox for DOS emulation)  ... BTW `MyBuild\ ` in emu is not 100% right. The trailing backslash is sort of wrong. And it's missing the initial `emu\...`, but that's probably how the emu8086 provides local disk space, not full disk.

Comment: "barely anything happened" is not a very specific problem description.  Especially because the question doesn't even say what you *expected* to happen.  See [mcve].  Anyway, use a debugger to step through it if there are still any mysteries.